# How to get time from XmlGregorianCalendar

Tags: java

I need to set time in the format of `http //www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema:time`. I have a `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar` object with the value `1970-01-01T08:11:04.274+01:00`.

How to get the `time("08:11:04.274")` from this?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
XMLGregorianCalendar time = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
  .newXMLGregorianCalendarTime(xgc.getHour(), xgc.getMinute(), xgc.getSecond(), 
      xgc.getFractionalSecond(), xgc.getTimezone());
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
Date time = xmlgregcal.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String formatted = sdf.format(time);
```

Cheers,
Matthias